# TypeError in JavaScript, Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typeerror

I'm currently developing a Webapps using the Google Maps API. I want to plot X different routes simultaneosly to the same destination location.

If I plot one, it works, but when I work with arrays (Because I don't know how many routes I will plot finally) it shows me this type of errors. The code when calculating the routes is like these.

```
var rendererOptions = [];
var directionsDisplay = [];

for (var k = 0; k < carLatLng.length; k++) {

    rendererOptions[k] = {
        map: map
    };
    directionsDisplay[k] = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions[k]);

    var request = {
        origin: carLatLng[k],
        destination: place.geometry.location,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay[k].setDirections(response);

        } else alert('Failed to get directions');
    });

}
```

The error tells me `TypeError: directionsDisplay[k] is undefined`. (It refers to the one inside the `if()` clause)

Hope guys you could help me. I have tried some options but none of them works. Only works when I eliminate the for loop (and the array-type)

Thank you

Comment: It might be because `k` is not defined inside your `directionsService.route` function.

Comment: `k` is definitely not undefined - `directionsDisplay[k]` is undefined

Comment: Thank you all. But maybe I don't deserve that much negative score...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`directionsService.route` is asynchronous - by the time the last repsonse is received, the loop would've run it's course, and `k == carLatLng.length` - thus `directionsDisplay[k]` will be undefined

What you need is to change

```
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay[k].setDirections(response);

    } else alert('Failed to get directions');
});
```

to something like

```
function(directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else alert('Failed to get directions');
    });
}(directionsDisplay[k]);
```

there's probably easier ways to make a closure, but my mind is addled at the moment

edit: for some clarity, maybe, hopefully -

```
function(captured_k) {
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay[captured_k].setDirections(response);
        } else alert('Failed to get directions');
    });
}(k);
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I don't understand very well why this work (I understand what the problem was and why my code didn't work) but I don't understand well how your solution solves the asynchronous problem... For me your code is the same as mine's. Anyway, thank you a lot.

Comment: it's to do with the fact that there's an asynchronous function in the loop - the value of k keeps going up while the asynch function is waiting to complete, by the time the last asynch function completes, k is almost certainly guaranteed to be too big. Using a closure, 'captures' the value of k in the IIFE (google it), actually, I've 'captured' the directionsDisplay[k] object, but it's the same thing